# Do domains point to default Community Alphabetically?

Tags: community, force.com-sites

I have a Community that begins with "c". I have a domain. When I go to this Domain, it goes to this Community's Site. Great!

I made another Community that begins with "n" - just upon making it (I thought the ONLY way to get to it would be mydomain/communityName), my domain automatically directed to this new community site!

I read in some documentation (which I can't find...will update question with this later!) that it chooses this by alphabetical order by default - which makes no sense to me, because I thought you just have the specific path, unless using a URL redirect to point root (/) to site (ex. mydomain/ ---> mydomain/someCommunitySite)

The doc (will provide when possible) says it will choose this way unless you specify in "Site Primary Custom URL", which is a setting I cannot find for the life of me.

How do I ensure that my domain is ONLY associated with the site I want, without worrying about my other communities/sites?

This was an INSANELY complicated question for Support, whom I've been contacting for DAYS with no proper understanding, so I'm hoping somebody here can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, when a community URL is specified without the actual community prefix, the last created community is the one displayed (even if the current user has no access to said community).

From the question, I'm guessing that you have registered a domain (e.g. www.yourdomain.com) and want that to point to a specific SF community.

If this is the case, then you will need to set up a "Domain" in SF (under "Domains" in the setup search bar or Domain Management|Domains).  It sounds like you have already completed this step.

Then you will need to associate that domain with your community (or site).  In setup, type in "Sites" or navigate to Develop|Sites.

From here select the community you want to associate with your domain.  Click "New Custom URL".  Here you will be able to select the domain you have created, and specify that it is the "Site Primary Custom URL".

You are able to use the same domain for multiple communities by specifying a path too (e.g. community 1 = www.yourdomain.com/site1, community 2 = www.yourdomain.com/site2).

Also, you will need to have an SSL certificate for your domain name.

I hope I have understood the issue correctly.  If not, get back to me and I'll elaborate further.

Comment: Hey there - thanks for your response! I do have a clarifying question. What do you mean by this? "when a community URL is specified without the actual community prefix, the last created community is the one displayed (even if the current user has no access to said community)." Community prefix..? If this matters, we got a "my" domain with salesforce, and this is what's used by default when creating the community.

Comment: The domain is greyed-out, and all I can specify is the path (so like, mydomain.force.com/communityname). So I assumed that this is the unique path for this community

Comment: @NataliePaige Yes, the path (aka prefix) makes up the url for this community.  You should have two my salesforce domains by default.  The internal domain (you.my.salesforce.com) and your communities domain (you.force.com).  Basically, if you have no communities with a blank path, you.force.com will direct you to the latest created community.

Comment: Thanks so much! You're helping me infinitely more than two weeks of Support that can't seem to understand anything about my question, so thank you!!! I think the bottom line is, and correct me if I'm wrong, if my initial Community was associated with mydomain.force.com rather than mydomain.force.com/whateverPath, then it would always go there by default - but because both communities have a path, the default is the latest created? How can I keep the path on my initial one, but make it the default? Just URL redirects from root to that in the other Site?

Comment: Is "Site Primary Custom URL" only an option when setting up the domain? Does this prevent the root URL from directing to latest Community?

Comment: Hey Natalie, sorry for my late reply.  All that the "Primary" URL does is set which URL shows by default in the browser.  Lets just say you have you.force.com/partners and yourcustomdomain.com both setup as "Custom URLs" for the same community.  If you type in you.force.com/partners in your browser, the URL will change to yourcustomdomain.com in the browser if that URL is set as the "Primary URL".